# Disconnecting from the server after sending file

Tags: c#, tcp, client, listener, sendfile

I'm trying to send file from TCP client to listener. Its all working but after the file is sent, the client is disconnecting from the server. Here is the code I'm currently using for the client:

```
public static void SendFile(FileInfo file)
{
    try
    {  
        long size = file.Length;

        using (NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream())
        {
            using (FileStream Fs = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                int num;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[Fs.Length];
                while ((num = Fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    ns.Write(buffer, 0, num);
                }
                Fs.Close();
                ns.Close();
            }
        }

        FileInfo p_c = new FileInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\destfile.bin");
        p_c.Delete();
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

and for the server:

```
using (NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(current))
{
    using (FileStream Fs = new FileStream(full_path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
    {        
        while ((RecBytes = ns.Read(RecData, 0, RecData.Length)) > 0)
        {
            Fs.Write(RecData, 0, RecBytes);
            totalrecbytes += RecBytes;
        }
        {
        Fs.Close();
        ns.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("File received. Path: {0}", full_path);
    }      
}
```

Comment: the `}{` brackets in the server code, above `Fs.Close();` can't be correct for a start.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `NetworkStream.Close()` or `NetworkStream.Dispose` (at the end of the `using` clause) will terminate the connection.

If you want to keep the socket open, use the [NetworkStream(Socket, bool)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te7e60bx(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor and and pass false as the second parameter.

Comment: If i dont call it, I wont be able to use the file unless I quit the programs.

Comment: `Dispose();` will be called automatically when using the `using` statement

Comment: @smirnoFzRPM Dispose the FileStream, keep the NetworkStream.